# htaccess http_host question about www

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using the following rule to redirect `domain.com` to `https://mail.google.com/a/domain.com` so my clients can check their mail.

```
RewriteRule ^mail https://mail.google.com/a/%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L,NC]
```

The problem is `www.domain.com` ends up at `https://mail.google.com/a/www.domain.com` which is incorrect. Is there any variable that does not include the www. ? Alternatively, can someone help me stripping it out?

As a tangent issue: Does anyone know of a web tool for testing htaccess files? I encounter a lot of caching problems when testing htaccess and I was thinking a simple simulation environment would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RewriteCond and match for the the domain name. After that you can backreference it in the RewriteRule, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ([^.]+(\.|\.co\.|\.com\.)[^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^e?mail       https://mail.google.com/a/%1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

`([^.]+\.[^.]+)$` would match the last two sections of your domain, separated by a dot.

**Edit:** `([^.]+(\.|\.co\.)[^.]+)$` would match DOMAIN.TLD and DOMAIN.co.TLD too.

**Edit2:** `^e?mail` means DOMAIN.TLD/mail and DOMAIN.TLD/email would redirect

**Edit3:** `([^.]+(\.|\.co\.|\.com\.)[^.]+)$` form DOMAIN.com.TLD, and a bit of correction, was missing a dot.

Comment: Using same logic, would something like this work? `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.*?)`

Comment: @cronoklee yes, that was my first answer, but corrected it to this one. I thought more subdomains are possible to occure, but i add the co part in a sec.

Comment: Cool thanks - Also if I want to also redirect ^email to the same url, is it necessary to rewrite the RewriteCond line or does the %1 stay in memory?

Comment: @cronoklee actually no, `www.(.*?)` would not work. Instead `^(www\.)?(.*)$`, and the backreference shoud be `%2`

Comment: Added the part to match `email` too.

Comment: @crinoklee I do not know how big variety of domains you want to handle, but here is another widely used format for commercial sites: `domain.com.xx` (for example: `com.ua` (Ukraine), `com.au` (Australia) etc

Comment: @LazyOne `([^.]+(\.|\.co\.|\.com\.)[^.]+)$` would handle that as well :)

Comment: @inti I know -- I just was offering @cronoklee to consider those domains as well (in case if he will be dealing with such domains).

Comment: @LazyOne ok, but I'm thankful to you, since I found a mistake in my regex when I was adding that .com part, so thanks :)